# Supremum of product of two functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, supremum-and-infimum

If I am given two continuous functions
 $ f, g : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
with $g(x)\geq 0$, then is it true that $\sup(fg) \leq \sup(\sup(f) g)$?

The stronger conjecture that $\sup(fg) \leq \sup(f)\sup(g)$ is false, as we can take $[a,b] = [0,1]$, $f = -1$, and $g = x$. Then $\sup(fg) = 0$, but $\sup(f)\sup(g) = -1(1) = -1 < 0$.

A counterexample or outline of a proof would be appreciated.

Edit: $g(x) \geq 0$ instead of $\mid g(x)\mid \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $f(x) = g(x) = -x$ on $[0,1]$.

Or did you mean $g(x) \ge 0$?  In that case, 
$f g \le \sup(f) g$ so $\sup(fg) \le \sup(\sup(f) g)$.

Comment: Yes I meant $g(x) \geq 0$, the absolute value signs don't really mean anything there. Thanks for the correction.